# How to make Bitmaps smaller?

Tags: android, eclipse, canvas, bitmap

I got a Canvas all over my screen-and a thread that alwayse drawing it again and again.I want to draw some Bitmaps(pictures of balls) that will become smaller and smaller when my app is running.
How can I do this?
It's really important to me, thank you all,
Itay.

```
public class OurView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{//to make it to a trhead

    float width,height;//בשביל ייצוג האורך והרוחב של המסך
    Point size = new Point();
    Random r =new Random();//בשביל להגריל מיקום לכדור
    Thread t=null;//הגדרת הטראד של החלק הזה
    SurfaceHolder holder;//דרך להתנהל עם הטראד
    boolean isItOk=false;//לקבוע מתי הקאנביס מפסיק לצייר את עצמו
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();//בשביל האורך והרוחב של המסך
    public OurView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        width=this.getWidth();
        height=this.getHeight();
        holder= getHolder();


    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        this.width = size.x;
        this.height = size.y;
        /*      x = (r.nextInt(width-redball.getWidth()));
        y=(r.nextInt(height-redball.getHeight()));
         */     
        height=(float) (height*0.85);
        int marginX= Math.round(width-redball.getWidth());
        int marginY =Math.round(height-redball.getHeight());
        x = r.nextInt(marginX);
        y=r.nextInt(marginY);
        while(isItOk==true&&pressed!=true){
            if (!holder.getSurface().isValid()) 
                continue;
            Canvas c= holder.lockCanvas();
            c.drawRGB(0, 0, 0);
            c.drawBitmap(redball, x, y, null);//אם רוצים שמרכז המעגל יהיה, אפשר לעשות חלק 2. אולי אופציה להעלאת רמה.
            c.
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }
        if(pressed==true){
            Canvas c= holder.lockCanvas();
            c.drawRGB(0, 0, 0);
            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a method to scale ball and draw its on AsyncTask because drawing much bitmap create memory leak.

Comment: Thanks!
But im not sure that I understod you right.
I added the code that draw my balls(excelly now its just 1 ball, im not sure how to make it draw several balls by himself)- can you take a look and tell me if it can cause memory leak? I understod that the surfaceview is a good way to work with treads and Canvas.

Comment: You can use bitmap.recycle() or bitmap = null before create another bitmap, this is good way for bypass memory leak

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()
```

to this you add the x,y size and it will return to you the new sized bitmap

Comment: Why this function asks me for a bollean?
Is this going to do the work:(I want it to get smaller slowly, and I wrote this line in the loop that drawing the bitmap and the canvas).
redball.createScaledBitmap(redball,redball.getWidth()-1,redball.getHeight()-1,true);